# Create an asp.net authentication cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies

We have will have a mixed ASP.NET environment with WebForms, MVC and some SPA sections.

Now I would like to implement one of these login forms that just pop up with you hover over the login link. This would require that we can authenticate the user via Web Service call (not an issue). But in order to stay compatible with the rest of the pages, we need to set the ASP.NET authentication cookie in the browser. So that it works for the other pages.

Is that possible?
Or is the only way to use an iframe with the login form that reloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the Auth Cookie on the server side

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, remeberMe);
```

and update the login view with a logged-in one.

Comment: Right, but that runs a bit against the idea of an ajax call with no full-page postback.

Comment: You don't need a full page postback, just set the auth cookie on the ajax called mvc action, or whatever endpoint, and return a partial view or just a Json to update the piece of HTML for logged user.

Comment: Right, the cookie is indeed part of the JSON response. Unfortunately, it's HttpOnly, so I cannot read it and assign it to the page. It's not transferred automatically.